# Why doesn't this use of html_decode_entities work?

Tags: php

This code is adapted from the PHP manual entry on html_entity_decode()

```
protected function decode($data)
{
    $data = html_entity_decode($data, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
    //echo $data;
    return $data;
}
protected function decode_data($data)
{

    if(is_object($data) || is_array($data)){
        array_walk_recursive($data,array($this,'decode'));
    }else{
        $data = html_entity_decode($data, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
    }
    return $data;
}
```

If data contains an a value like `Children&#39;s` it does not get decoded to `Children's`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `html_entity_decode`, you're doing that right if you want to decode just quote entities, even those like `&#39;`.

Instead your problem is that you weren't using `array_walk_recursive` correctly.  In the following I used an anonymous function and pass the value as a reference:

```
function decode_data($data)
{
    if(is_object($data) || is_array($data)){
        // &$val, not $val, otherwise the array value wouldn't update.
        array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$val, $index) {
            $val = html_entity_decode($val, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
        });
    }else{
        $data = html_entity_decode($data, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
    }
    return $data;
}
$array = [
     "Children&#39;s",
     "Children&#39;s",
];
print_r( decode_data($array) );
```

Outputs both Children's as a single quote character and not as entity.

Comment: Thanks, this sorted it.